# Alternatives for innerHTML in jQuery

Tags: security-review

This might seem a question not related to this forum.

But, according to Salesforce Security reviews, we are not supposed to use innerHTML in our code. Since, this could cause Cross-Site-Scripting(XSS) issues as mentioned here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Scripting

e.g., 
`element.innerHTML = '<htmlcode>may be some script as well</htmlcode>';`

Could you please suggest, how to replace the best way? Or, with function that is not unsupported by Salesforce

Comment: Can you provide any supporting documentation for your claim that `innerHTML` is not supported? Using [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) from `jQuery` would at least avoid using it directly, but it may still do so under the hood.

Comment: updated question with the link @AdrianLarson

Comment: Can you provide any additional detail about where your content is coming from? It may add helpful context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a solution which might just work:

For static content: 
    - Use jQuery text method

For dynamic variables:
    - Use javascript escape to escape any HTML content
    - Use jQuery text method

For HTML content:
    - Generate the DOM elements using document.createElement();
    - Set the dynamic variables to be displayed on screen as text inside the DOM elements
    - Set the attributes of DOM elements using attribute property after using Javascript escape

Answer (score -2):

Salesforce do not unsupported innerHtml but saying that it could be a way to attack your page.

If you can sanitize your string before adding it to DOM element, it is all okay.

You can do it by using `escapeSingleQuotes` on server side

Or you can also do like below:

```
{! SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($Request.title,"<","<"),">",">")}
```

or you can also remove all unwanted active content before adding to dom using javascript as per your need.

I Hope this will help you.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. escapeSingleQuotes is only for SOSL/SOQL where you're using dynamic queries. Also, your substitute won't fully prevent injection either client-side.

Comment: For example, see this article here about the various dangers of simply replacing html arbitrarily without considering the consequences: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet. Using innerHTML without serious consideration could break stuff.